# Count of an element in a matrix using Divide & Conquer

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, divide-and-conquer

I'm starting to learn how to implement divide and conquer algorithms, but I'm having some trouble with this exercise.

I have written an algorithm but unfortunately it returns a 0 value. I need to count how many times a number finds in the matrix using D&C.

My idea is to divide the matrix in 4 sub-matrices till all coordinates are equal, it means that there is an element (could be my number or not).

My abbreviations:

```
lr - left row   | starting with 
lc- left column | left lower corner
rr - right row    | starting with
rc- right column  |  right upper corner
```

When I compile, **it runs well but returns 0** (because of my stop statement I think). **So, my error is in solve() function.**

My code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin("in.txt");
#define debug cerr<<"OK";
int n,a[100][100];
int solve(int lr,int lc, int rr,int rc,int x,int &contor)
{
    int cnt=0;
    if(lr < rr || lc > rc)
    {
        if(cnt<=0)
            return 0;
        return cnt;
    }
        if(lr == lc && rr == rc)
        if(a[lr][lc] == x)
            cnt++;
        else;
    else
    {
        int l=(lr+rr)/2;
        int c=(lc+rc)/2;
        if(l && c)
        {
        int cnt1=solve(lr-l,lc,rr,rc-c,x,contor); // coordinates for upper left square
        int cnt2=solve(lr-l,lc+c,rr,rc,x,contor); // -||- for upper right square
        int cnt3=solve(lr,lc,rr+l,rc-c,x,contor); // -||- for low left square 
        int cnt4=solve(lr,lc+c,rr,rc-c,x,contor); // -||- for low right square
        contor=cnt1+cnt2+cnt3+cnt4;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{  
    fin>>n;
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        fin>>a[i][j];
    int contor=0;
solve(n,1,1,n,3,contor);  // i'm searching for 3
   cout<<contor;
    _getch();
   fin.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Maybe you can tell me where the problem is or directly solve it, it would be faster and I can understand easier.

```
Input:
4
1 3 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: `cnt` should not be a global variable. Instead you should return the according values (sum the return values of sub-calls when you do the division). Furthermore, the division coordinates look a bit strange. Shouldn't the top left square just be `lr, l, lc, c`? A more meaningful variable naming is desirable, so other people (including you in a week) can understand what you mean.

Comment: The coordinates of my above comment are probably wrong. Your naming convention is just too confusing to me. My suggestion: `min1` and `max1` for the first dimension and `min2` and `max2` for the second. Another mistake is your initialization. Array indices are zero-based, so you should specify the area from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i tried, but as i answered to @marom, i'm getting a very large number. Yes, they're wrong, i wrote clearly that i'm starting with left lower corner and right upper corner. I know, but i started with index 1 to be easier to count the rows and columns.

Comment: But if you start with 1, you are accessing the wrong array elements. You're probably getting large numbers because `cnt` is not initialized to `0`. This problem wouldn't even exist if `cnt` wasn't a global variable.

Comment: I modified my code, what about now? I'm still getting a large number

Comment: Well, for one, you print out `cnt` which is a local variable in `main`, which should remain at `0` forever. Second, the `contor+=cnt1+cnt2+cnt3+cnt4;` line is wrong because you add thing to `contor` that have been added before. Third, you don't return anything in the division case. If you use the return value, you get undefined values.

Comment: Can you solve this thing for me? Just implement the function, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Is this homework? Or where is this exercise from?

Comment: Nope, i'm solving exercises from a book for my knowledge! I'm learning divide & conquer next year at school, so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected source code. I have added some comments so you can follow it. Furthermore, I switched to a dynamic array of the correct size.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int countOccurences(int** values, int min1, int min2, int max1, int max2, int searchValue)
{
    if (min1 > max1 || min2 > max2)
        return 0; //invalid area

    if (min1 == max1 && min2 == max2)
    {
        //the current area is a single cell
        if (values[min1][min2] == searchValue)
            return 1; //we have found 1 occurence
        else
            return 0; //we have found nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //divide the current range
        int center1 = (min1 + max1) / 2;
        int center2 = (min2 + max2) / 2;

        int occurencesInSubMatrices = 0;

        //accumulate the occurences in the according variable
        occurencesInSubMatrices += countOccurences(values, min1, min2, center1, center2, searchValue); // coordinates for upper left square
        occurencesInSubMatrices += countOccurences(values, center1 + 1, min2, max1, center2, searchValue); // -||- for upper right square
        occurencesInSubMatrices += countOccurences(values, min1, center2 + 1, center1, max2, searchValue); // -||- for low left square 
        occurencesInSubMatrices += countOccurences(values, center1 + 1, center2 + 1, max1, max2, searchValue); // -||- for low right square
        return occurencesInSubMatrices;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("in.txt");
    int n;
    fin >> n;

    //create a 2d array of appropriate size
    int** values = new int*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //allocate memory for the i-th row
        values[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fin >> values[i][j];
    }

    int count = countOccurences(values, 0, 0, n - 1, n - 1, 3);  // i'm searching for 3
    cout << count;
    _getch();
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Please be aware that this is a purely educational example. In the real world, nobody would count ocurrences like this.

Comment: Of course not, just to understand the D&C concept better! Thank you

Comment: One more thing, why do you use int** ?

Comment: It's called a jagged array. Every row is a one-dimensional array (pointer to int, which is `int*`). The 2d array is basically a one-dimensional array of those arrays (an array of `int*`, hence `int**`).

Comment: Okay, one more question, why you use same coordinates for both mins and maxes? I mean with what corner do you start with min1 & max1 and min2 & max2? And which is the row and which is the column?

Comment: Because both dimensions (horizontal and vertical) have the same extent (min = 0, max = n-1). The notion of rows and columns depends on the interpretation. Rows in the input file have the same coordinate on the first dimension. Hence, the first dimension specifies the row, the second dimension specifies the column.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion does not update cnt...

```
    if(l && c)
    {
    solve(lr-l,lc,rr,rc-c,x); // coordinates for upper left square 
    solve(lr-l,lc+c,rr,rc,x); // -||- for upper right square
    solve(lr,lc,rr+l,rc-c,x); // -||- for low left square 
    solve(lr,lc+c,rr,rc-c,x); // -||- for low right square
    }
```

Comment: I tried something but now i'm getting a very large number! Can you edit your post and make it more relevant?